# Return multiple values from function prototype in C. Results are multiple products

Tags: c, return-value, function-prototypes, multiple-value

So I have a function prototype find all products from two numbers whether it has 2 or 3 digits. I believe that function can only return one value. So how do I print out all possible values in main using printf statement?

```
int find_largest_products(int ndigits){
    
    int min = 1;
    int max;
    int smallest_num;
    int largest_num = 0;
    int product = 0;
    int max_min_product = 0;

    //Finding the minima. 1 digit = 1; 2 digits = 10; 3 digits = 100
    smallest_num = min * pow(10, ndigits-1);
    

    //Finding the maxima. 1 digits = 9; 2 digits = 99; 3 digits = 999
    for (int i = 0; i < ndigits; i++){
        max  =  9 * pow(10, i);
        largest_num += max;
    }
    

    
    for (int x = largest_num; x >= smallest_num; x--){
        for (int y = smallest_num; y <= largest_num; y++){
            product = x * y;
            max_min_product = product;
        }
        
    }
    return max_min_product;
    
}



 
int main() {
    
    int num = find_largest_palindrome(2);
    printf("Results: %d\n", num);        
   
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Use a callback function?

Comment: Common options: 1. Caller passes in a buffer/array which the function can fill in. Function can return the number of items filled in. 2. Function allocates dynamic array and returns that. Caller is responsible for freeing the memory.

Comment: I see! Thank you. Can I still use a buffer or an array to encapsulate all those return values? Because there are several two or three hundred values to be return since 99*11, 99*12, 99*13,...,etc.

Comment: Why not? Buffer just needs to be big enough. Caller should pass in the buffer size to ensure function does not write past the end of the buffer.

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you very much. I'm still new to programming in C. What if you don’t know what the buffer size is beforehand?

Comment: Guess, allocate, `realloc()` if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Callback function:

```
int find_largest_products(int ndigits, int (*callback)(int, void *), void *baton){
        //...
             //max_min_product = product;
             int r= callback(product, baton);
             if (r) return r;
        //...
    return 0;
}

int print_product(int product, void *ignored) {
    printf(" %d", product);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //...
    printf("Results:");
    find_largest_products(2, print_product, NULL); // Invocation is here
    printf("\n");
    //...
}
```

What about commas? What about newline every so many? We can adapt the callback.

```
int print_product(int product, void *baton) {
    int *counter = baton;
    if (counter % 8 == 7) {
        printf(", %d\n", product);
    else if (counter % 8 == 0)
        printf("%d\n", product);
    else
        printf(", %d\n", product);
    ++*counter;
    return 0;
}
```

But now the invocation should look like:

```
    int counter = 0;
    find_largest_products(2, print_product, &counter); // Invocation is here
```

Notice how this keeps state between invocations. Here it's an `int`, but it could easily be a `struct` or a pointer thereof to enable keeping arbitrary amounts of state.

So this is the pattern of a callback function that can do whatever it wants. The callback function takes the accumulating argument found by find_largest_products and the state argument baton from find_largest_products, and returns 0 to continue or nonzero to bail. Here the callback function only prints the value out and never fails. I also consider this lower-skill-level than dynamic memory. We only need to learn the somewhat annoying syntax for function pointers and the rest easy concepts. Note that we don't take the address of a function pointer with &; it's like an array in that regard.

To make the point this is the general form; here's the callback that could be passed to retrieve the list.

```
struct product_info {
    int *products;
    int nproducts;
    int aproducts;
};

int gather_products(int product, void *baton)
{
    struct product_info *info = baton;
    // normal dynamic stretchy array zzzzz
    if (info->nproducts == info->aproducts) {
        if (info->aproducts == 0) {
            info->products = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
            if (!info->products) return 1;
            info->aproducts = 0;
        } else {
            void *more = realloc(sizeof(int) * (info->aproducts << 1));
            if (!more) return 1;
            info->aproducts <<= 1;
            info->products = more;
        }
    }
    // end stretchy array
    info->products[info->nproducts++] = product;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    //...
    printf("Results: ");
    struct product_info info = { NULL, 0, 0 };
    if (find_largest_products(2, gather_products, &info)) { // Invocation is here
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        free(info->products);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < info->nproducts; i++)
        printf("%s%d", (i == 0) ? "" : ", ", info->products[i]);
    free(info->products);
    printf("\n");
    //...
}
```

Returning the list requires dynamic memory. It's interesting to note that function pointers provides a separation of concerns that I've come to appreciate in these late days; we can separate the generating algorithm from the storing of the results.

Another sample: find biggest!

```
int biggest_product(int product, void *baton) {
    int *biggest = baton;
    if (*biggest < product) *biggest = product;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int biggest = 0;
    find_largest_products(2, biggest_product, &biggest); // Invocation is here
    printf("Biggest product is: %d\n", biggest);
}
```

Notice how easy it is to swap what you do with the products as you generate them.